# Creating multiple tasks in a batch using Asana API?

Tags: batch-processing, asana

I have written a piece of Google Apps Script code that searches for all Action Items -- AIs in a doc, and creates Asana tasks from them. This is awesome, except for one annoying problem -- it takes a pretty long time 5-10 seconds to assign all tasks, since I am making separate requests for each.

I am trying to see if there is a way to add multiple tasks in a batch request. I've tried looking in the API docs, and it has nothing on this topic, but maybe there is some undocumented way of using the API to do this?

Or if not, please consider this as a feature request, Asana team!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have some ideas for batch-adding tasks, but you're right, it's not currently available. And no, no secret undocumented endpoint either ... *yet.*

Comment: Thanks, agnoster, please keep me posted!

Comment: i second this feature

Comment: Would love to see this feature as well.